# How to Work With "SyntaxError : (unicode error)" in a script on Windows?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I'm writing a Python script on a Windows OS that needs to find a specific file in the Downloads directory and then automatically send an email with that specific file attached. The issue I'm running into is when I try to attach the file using the file path.

I run into the `SyntaxError: (unicode error)` because of the single backslash in the file path `file_path = "C:\Users\...`.

Obviously, I can just add another backslash manually to make it read the file properly like so `file_path = "C:\\Users\...`

But if I plan on running this script every day, I don't want to manually add that second backslash in every time.

I've tried the following with no luck.

First attempt:

```
import os

file_path = "C:\Users\mmacwan\Downloads\...
file_path.replace(os.sep, '//')
```

Second attempt:

```
try:
    file_path = "C:\Users\mmacwan\Downloads\...
except SyntaxError:
     print('Bypassed SyntaxError')
```

Third attempt:

```
from path lib import Path

file_path = os.path.normpath("C:\Users\mmacwan\Downloads\...)
file_path.replace(os.sep,'//')
```

Comment: `r"C:\Users\mmacwan\Downloads\..."`

Comment: Prefix the string with an `r` — see *raw strings* in [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) section of the documentation. Also note that you *can* use forward slashes on Windows computers and avoid the whole issue (as well as be more portable). Another option would be to use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html#cap-p) module (and forward slashes).